# Android - mediaplayer and notifications

Tags: android, service, notifications, media-player, interrupt

I currently have a streaming `mediaplayer` that runs in a `service`. Whenever I receive a text message, my mediaplayer halts, stops buffer, and either continues or not. Is there anyway to disable incoming notifications so it doesn't interrupt the buffer/mediaplayer? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by adding the following code to my manifest file:

```
<receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver">
            <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

It worked like a charm